# Is it possible to have text styled italic but emoji styled as normal text in the same paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Say we have a text paragraph (p, div or what have you):

> Be nice. The world  is a small town

I would like the text in it to be italic, but emoji to have a normal font-style **without wrapping the emoji or any other text in additional tags**.

Answer (score 4):

*Be nice. The world*  *is a small town*

```
<p><i>Be nice. The world</i>  <i>is a small town</i> <p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, better way is to wrap emoji icons in an inline element like `<span>` and style in css.

```css
.emoji {
  font-style: normal;
}
p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>Be nice. The world <span class="emoji"></span> is a small town <span class="emoji"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is :

```
<p><i>Be nice. The world</i> :) <i>is a small town</i> :P </p>
```

alternatively you can use css to style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these

```css
x{
    font-style: italic;
}
span{
    font-style: italic;

}
```

```html
<p><x>Be niceThe world </x> &#9742 <x>is a small town </x> &#9742</p>

<p><span>Be niceThe world </span> &#9742 <span>is a small town </span> &#9742</p>
```